# making necklaces with beads problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Hello im working on this problem and im completely stuck

(a) there are 4 biz. How many necklase can I make?

(b)consider the set of all necklase with distinct biz, where the size of a necklace is the number of biz it contains. what is the counting sequence?

(c) consider two arrangements same( if one is obtained from the other by flipping). what is the counting sequence?

Comment: Are the beads in all parts of the problem all different colors and distinguishable from one another?  I'm assuming there is no clasp (i.e. we can't tell where the necklace "starts" and "ends")

Comment: Be very careful about the third problem. The "formula" is a little different for $n=1$ and $n=2$ than for larger $n$.

Comment: i guess its all distinguishable

Comment: You may be interested to read about "The Lemma that isn't Burnside's" which deals with the generalization of this problem to the possibility of beads of the same color.  To fully understand and appreciate it though requires a small bit of group-theory, so it might be a few semesters away in your future if you aren't taking a course specifically in combinatorics.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr: The short answer is that we can divide by the "symmetry" involved.  In other words, when we try to count how many sequences there are if in *every* case we over counted by the same amount, then we can divide by the number of times we counted each "different" case.  Divide by the number of possible "different" rotations and flips allowed.

---

Suppose we have four distinct beads, colored $A,B,C,D$.

We can then arrange the beads in a straight row (with a specific start and end) in $4!$ number of ways.

Note however, in trying to count like this, we accidentally counted $ABCD$, $BCDA$, $CDAB$, and $DABC$ seperately.  Similarly we overcounted all other "different arrangements" a total of four times each as well.  Dividing by the number of times each "different arrangement" was counted from the answer we calculated earlier gives us $\frac{4!}{4} = 3!$

A similar argument will show that for $n$ number of distinct beads, we will have each arrangement present in our list a total of $n$ times, for a final total of $\frac{n!}{n}=(n-1)!$ number of "different" arrangements.

Finally for if flips are allowed, note that in the special cases $n=1$ and $n=2$, if we rotate the necklace it is the same as flipping it.  A quick verification will show there is only one unique arrangement in both cases.

In $n\geq 3$ with flips allowed, referring back to the case of $n=4$ as above, our sequence $ABCD$ was the same as $BCDA, CDAB,$ and $DABC$ as above, but now also the same as $DCBA, CBAD, BADC$, and $ADCB$ for a total of 8 times we overcounted.  A similar argument will show that every "different" necklace was also counted a total of 8 times too many for a total of $\frac{4!}{8} = 3$ number of distinct necklaces.

Generalizing to arbitrary $n$, you get a total of $\frac{n!}{2n} = \frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ number of different necklaces.

Answer (score 0):

For all distinct beads:

(a) Pick one bead, this is your reference so that rotation can be ignored. Then place the other three beads say clockwise, choosing from 3, then 2, then 1. $3!=6$ options.

(b) obviously from above, the sequence is $(n-1)!$

(c) clockwise=counterclockwise; divide by 2 (except for extremely short necklaces :-), thanks @André ).